# TIP120 and Solenoid Gas Valve

Tags: arduino, power, transistors, current, solenoid

I have a Solenoid Normally Open gas valve rated at 29VA. It can be operated using 220VAC or 12/24/48 VDC. When i power it with AC mains voltage, it draws only 3mA @ 220V and the valve closes. When i power it with 12VDC nothing happens. I've tried controlling it using an Arduino with TIP120 but still it only draws 15mA @ 12VDC with a TIP120. My calculations say that it should draw about 2.4A @ 12VDC whith the rated power 29VA. whats wrong? why isn't it working and is only drawing 15mA?
*I'm powering it with a lab power supply rated @ 30VDC 5A by the way, just in case you needed to know.

Comment: Any datasheet? Brand? Model?

Comment: not much information about the solenoid... it's and ESKA EVG

Comment: Does its datasheet suggest anything about how it can operate on such different voltages? Like, say, it comes with different options according to the voltage and you have the 220V one?

Comment: @BrianDrummond no there is no such thing stated, just that it can run at the said voltages AC or DC : 12V, 24V, 48V, 110V, 220V AC or DC (On request other voltages).
The seller said that it runs on 12VDC with a battery.

Comment: No, it's quite clearly a range of valves - see https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http://www.eskavalve.com/ru/produkty/rucnoj-zavod-gazovyh-klapanov/gazovyj-klapan-serii-egv/16/ If you think it magically works off different voltages, then explain how it magically connects to a variety of different pipe threads.

Answer (score 1):

> It can be operated using 220VAC or 12/24/48 VDC

No it cannot.

The Eska EGV range is specified: -

- Working Voltage Range: 12V, 24V, 48V, 110V, 220V AC or DC (On request other voltages)
- Voltage Tolerance: ± %10

That does not mean that a 220 V AC coil will work at 12 volt. If you buy one rated for 220 V AC then it will work at 220 V AC +/- 10%.

Comment: I don't understand, it says on request other voltages correct? that means for example if we needed 70VDC...

Comment: By the way there is no proper information listed in the datasheet...

Comment: Yeah I took a quick look and removed that part of my answer.

Comment: You have to order the correct part. That model is available in 12VDC, 24VDC, 48VDC, 110VAC and 220VAC versions.

Comment: @Janka the problem is that there are no other versions, only one...

Comment: Datasheet: ( Turkish )
besleme gerilimi 12 v dc ve 230 v 50 hz ac olan normalde acik otomatik kapama 
Translation:
normally open automatic shutdown with supply voltage 12 V dc and 230 V 50 Hz AC
It says 12VDC or 230VAC, now what to do? XD XD

Comment: That's nonsense. AC solenoid coils also work with DC, but the DC voltage needed is about 1/3 of the AC voltage, not 1/19.

Comment: @Killerbee89 why would the spec say "On request other voltages" if it could work at 12 volts and 220 volts (and all voltages in between being the inference)?

Comment: @Andyaka I have no idea. That's why I've posted it here in the first place. The datasheet says that either 12VDC or 220VAC.

Comment: @Janka That too is an issue itself XD